# Thoughts on normal extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I've been reading up on Galois theory on my own; here are some thoughts of mine regarding normal extensions.

Let $K\subseteq L\subseteq M$ be fields such that the extension $M:K$ is algebraic. (This means $M:L$ is algebraic.)

- If $M:L$ is a normal extension, is $M:K$ necessarily normal?
- If $M:K$ is a normal extension, is $M:L$ necessarily normal?

(1) No. Consider $K=\mathbb Q$, $L=\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2\right)$, $M=\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt{\sqrt2}\right)$. Then $$M = \left\{a+b\sqrt{\sqrt2}+c\sqrt2+d\sqrt{2\sqrt2}:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q\right\}$$$$= \left\{\left(a+c\sqrt2\right)+\left(b+d\sqrt2\right)\sqrt{\sqrt2}:a+c\sqrt2,b+d\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2\right)\right\}$$ so $\left\{1,\sqrt{\sqrt2}\right\}$ is a basis for $M$ over $L$; hence $|M:L|=2$ and so $M:L$ is normal since any algebraic extension of degree $2$ is normal. However $x^4-2\in K[x]$ is irreducible over $K$, has $\sqrt{\sqrt2}$ as a root in $M$ but$$x^4-2=\left(x+\sqrt{\sqrt2}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{\sqrt2}\right)\left(x^2+\sqrt2\right)$$ does not split over $M$ and so $M:K$ is not normal.

(2) Yes, I think. Suppose $M:K$ is normal and let $f(x)\in L[x]$ be irreducible in $L$ with root $\alpha$ in $M$. Then $f(x)=kp(x)$ for some $k\in L$ where $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$. Since $M$ is algebraic over $K$, $\alpha$ is also the root of some polynomial $q(x)$ over $K$. As $M:K$ is normal, $q(x)$ splits over $M$. Now consider $q(x)$ as a polynomial over $L$. Both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have a common root in $M$; as the former is the minimal polynomial, it divides $q(x)$ over $L$; hence $p(x)$ splits over $M$, being the product of some or all of the linear factors of $q(x)$ over $M$. Thus $f(x)=kp(x)$ splits over $M$ as well. This shows that $M:L$ is normal.

Are my thoughts essentially correct? Have I missed out anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes. If $\alpha \in M$, let $p_L$ and $p_K$ denote the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$ and $K$, respectively. Clearly, $$\deg(p_K) \ge \deg(p_L),$$write$$p_K = q \cdot p_L + r,\text{ }0 \le \deg(r) < \deg(p_L),$$doing this inside $L[X]$, which is a Euclidean domain with respect to degrees. But then$$r(\alpha) = 0 \implies r = 0$$by minimality of $p_L$. So we have $p_L \mid p_K$. But $p_K$ splits completely in $M$, by normality of $M/K$, and hence so does $p_L$. Thus $M/L$ is also normal, as $\alpha \in M$ was arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are essentially correct. For (2) you can abstract out the crucial detail as the following theorem:

> Given any algebraic field extension $K / F$, we have $m_K(r) \mid m_F(r)$ in $K[t]$ for any $r$ that is algebraic over $K$.

In the above, $m_K(r)$ denotes the minimal polynomial of $r$ over $K$, similarly for $m_F(r)$, and the division of polynomials is within the polynomial ring over $K$.